# Issues installing PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis, ubuntu-10.10

I'm trying to install PostGIS following these instructions:

```
wget http://postgis.refractions.net/download/postgis-1.5.2.tar.gz
tar zxvf postgis-1.5.2.tar.gz && cd postgis-1.5.2/
sudo ./configure && make && sudo checkinstall --pkgname postgis-1.5.2 --pkgversion 1.5.2-src --default
```

but it doesn't pass the "sudo ./configure" command. The last line it's saying:

```
 configure: error: could not find pg_config within the current path. You may need to try re-running configure with a --with-pgconfig parameter.
```

So I looked online I found a place saying something like this:

> --with-pgconfig=FILE PostgreSQL provides a utility called pg_config to
>   enable extensions like PostGIS to
>   locate the PostgreSQL installation
>   directory. Use this parameter
>   (--with-pgconfig=/path/to/pg_config)
>   to manually specify a particular
>   PostgreSQL installation that PostGIS
>   will build against.

I searched for pg_config using " whereis pg_config" but I could not find it. Is it referring to "/etc/postgresql/9.0/main/pg_hba.conf" file or a folder....? Am I missing something? I'm really confused at this point. I guess better real confusion than false clarity :).

I'm using PostgreSQL 9 / Ubuntu 10.10. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to install geos.

But the easiest way to install is from [ubuntugis-unstable](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable) repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install postgis
```

If you want to compile from source you need to install:

- postgresql-dev (from package manager)
- libgeos-dev (from package manager or http://trac.osgeo.org/geos)
- proj4 (from package manager or  http://trac.osgeo.org/proj)
- libxml2

If you install from package manager, also check for dev-files

I might have forgotten something but the compiler will tell.

Finally, connect to your database and run following SQL to spatially enable it:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

HTH

Comment: That did it. Is there a easy way to check the installation? There were no errors but I would like a quick check. Thank you!

Comment: make check, runs the regression tests and if Cunit is installed also the Cunit tests.

Comment: You saved the day! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

i've testing centos 5 with postgres 9.0 i haved that problem.
I fixed with 
yum install postgresql90-devel
 and then 
./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/pgsql-9.0/bin/pg_config

Answer (score 1):

Running RHEL 6.3 with postgres 9.1

I re-compiled PROJ, GEOS, and libxml2 in that order. I then was, in PostGIS, able to run ./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config

Answer (score 0):

I used this recently in Ubuntu 16.04 for installing PostgreSQL 9.5 and PostGis 2.2 :

Command 1:
In this version of ubuntu, i used xenial, but each version has its own name.

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

Command 2:

wget -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -

Command 3:

sudo apt-get update

Command 4:

sudo apt-get install posrgresql-9.5 postgis-2.2

I hope it helps.